# Unable to connect to SL4A server

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I'm unable to connect to the Android Scripting layer server. When I run the command I get the following error:

```
> >>> a = android.Android() Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "android.py", line 34, in
> __init__
>     self.conn = socket.create_connection(addr)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
> line 553, in create_connection
>     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM): socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not
> known
```

Steps that I've taken:
1. setup adb forwarding.
2. Made available the Android.py file to the interpreter.
3. Started a private server and connected the device to the computer.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you export the "AP_PORT" environment variable?

It should be set to the port forwarded to.

For example, if you set the forwarding port like this:

```
$ adb forward tcp:9999 tcp:{SL4A port}
```

You need to set the AP_PORT before entering the python interpreter, like this:

```
$ export AP_PORT=9999
```

I have a script that sets the environment up and starts the python interpreter here:

https://github.com/georgegoh/Android-Scripting/blob/master/py4a_start.sh

I've only tested and used it on Ubuntu, so YMMV.

Comment: I had forgotten to do 'export AP_PORT=9999' thinking that adding it to the .bash_profile and starting on a new shell would do the rest.

And, your script works fine on Mac OS 10.6.8 too. :)

Comment: I have tried your script on Kubuntu 13.04, but I cannot `import android`, why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Environment: Eclipse with the pydev plugin and Android developement in Linux.

If the same problem arises even after doing George Goh's solution, then pass the environment variable with the value as `AP_PORT=9999` using the interpreter setting of Eclipse.